# How to combine navbar, dropdown and collapse in AngularStrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I have a quite typical scenario:

- AngularJS (currently 1.2, want to upgrade to 1.3/1.4 soon)
- Bootstrap 3.x
- AngularStrap 2.1.x

As top-level menu I place a navbar with some dropdown menus and I'd like it to be collapsable for smaller devices (tablet portrait, phone).

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"
     ng-controller="MenuCtrl" bs-navbar>
    <div class="container-fluid" bs-collapse start-collapsed="true">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                    bs-collapse-toggle>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ACME</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" bs-collapse-target>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown" bs-dropdown>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                       data-toggle="dropdown"
                       id="tst-dropdown-session">
                       Session <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/api/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Of course above code is reduced compared to my real code)

The problem is: when clicking on the top-menu item, only a small dropdown shows up (~10px height) without sub-menu items.

**Does anybody have a working example for this?**

I could manage the menu items in a model of the controller, but how does "collapse" work then? Any ideas?

**Edit (add pictures)**

On narrow devices it should not look like this:

[image: narrow dropdown looking like desktop]

But it should more like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Define your menu items in controller.

And use it your html template as follows

**HTML code**

```
<li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropdown" bs-dropdown="dropdownHtml">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
       id="tst-dropdown-session">
       Session <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
</li>
```

**Controller code**

```
$scope.dropdownHtml = [
    {
        text: "Login",
        href: '#/login',
        title: 'Log out'
    },
    {
        text: "Logout",
        href: '/api/auth/logout',
        title: 'Log out'
    }
];
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for desktop, but it's not how it should behave and look on smaller devices like phone (see edit and screenshots).